# Gradebook Display Error C

Tags: c

I have this gradebook program I am writing and I cannot determine where my error is. I am not displaying the results correctly. Here is a sample of what I am supposed to run and what the results are supposed to look like:

```
ID, NAME, GRADE
2442
Kapowski, Kelly
87 99 100 87 88 -99
1254
Slater, A.C.
90 100 -99
8742
Morris, Zack
77 65 50 80 66 -99
```

Results:

```
Welcome to the automated grade book program. Version 2.0
Enter Student data filename:grades.txt
Name                 ID    Average Grade Scores
Kapowski, Kelly      2442     92.2     A  87  99 100  87  88
Morris, Zack         8742     67.6     D  77  65  50  80  66
Slater, A.C.         1254     95.0     A  90 100
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME 50
#define MAX_SCORES 20
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 100

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    int id;
    double scores[MAX_SCORES];
    int num_scores;

} student_t;

double student_average (student_t student);
FILE * get_data_file();
void get_data(student_t students[], int num_students, FILE *input_file);
void sort_student_array(student_t students[], int num_students);
int find_index_of_next(const student_t students[], int num_elements, int start_index);
void display_data(const student_t students[], int num_elements);

int main() {

   student_t *students;
    FILE *input_file;
    int num_students;

    input_file = get_data_file();

    //Get the number of students in the data file
    fscanf (input_file, "%d", &num_students);

   //Dynamically allocate the student array
    students = (student_t *)calloc(num_students, sizeof(student_t));

    // Get the student data
    get_data(students, num_students, input_file);

    // Sort the array alphabetically
    sort_student_array(students, num_students);

    // Display the student data
    display_data(students, num_students);

    // Free the space allocated to the array
    free(students);

    return 0;
}

//For each of the student's scores, divide the total points by the number of scores      
double student_average (student_t student) {

    double average;
    double total;
    int count;

    for (count = 0; count < student.num_scores; count++)
        total += student.scores[count];

    average = total / student.num_scores;

    return average;
}

//Read in the data file and make sure it is valid
FILE * get_data_file() {

    int valid = 0;
    char file_name[MAX_FILE_NAME];
    FILE *in_file;

    printf("Welcome to the automated grade book program. Version 2.0\n");

    do {
        printf ("Enter student data filename:");
        scanf ("%s", file_name);
        in_file = fopen (file_name, "r");

        if (in_file != NULL){
            valid = 1;
        } else {
            printf ("Unable to open file %s. Try again.\n", file_name);
        }
    } while (!valid);

    return in_file;
}

//Read data for each student
void get_data(student_t students[], int num_students, FILE *input_file) {

    int count;
    int count2;
    student_t student;
    double value;

    for (count = 0; count < num_students; count++) {
        //Read the student id number
        fscanf (input_file, "%d\n", &student.id);
        //Read the student name
        fgets (student.name, MAX_NAME, input_file);
        //Remove the newline from the name
        student.name[strlen(student.name)-1] = '\0';
        //Read the student test scores
        fscanf(input_file, "%lf", &value);

        count2 = 0;
        while (value != -99){
            student.scores[count2] = value;
            fscanf(input_file, "%lf", &value);
            count2++;
        }

        //Store count2 as the number of test scores for the student
        student.num_scores = count2;
        //Store the student in the student array
        students[count] = student;
    }
}

//Sort the students alphabetically
void sort_student_array(student_t students[],int num_students) {

    int count;
    int index_of_first;
    student_t temp;

    for (count = 0; count < num_students - 1; count++) {
        index_of_first = find_index_of_next(students, num_students, count);

        if (index_of_first != count) {
            temp = students[count];
            students[count] = students[index_of_first];
            students[index_of_first] = temp;
        }
    }
}

// For each student in the list, Test if the student's name in count is
// before the student's name in index_of_first
int find_index_of_next(const student_t students[], int num_elements, int start_index) {
    int count,
        index_of_first = start_index;

    for (count = start_index; count < num_elements; count++){
        if (strcmp(students[count].name, students[index_of_first].name) < 0)
            index_of_first = count;
    }

    return index_of_first;
}
//Displays the student data in proper format
void display_data(const student_t students[], int num_elements){
    int count;
    int index;
    double average;
    char grade;


    printf ("\nName                 ID   Average Grade Scores\n");


    for(count = 0; count < num_elements; count++) {
        printf ("%-20s", students[count].name);

        printf (" %-4d", students[count].id);

        average = student_average(students[count]);
        printf (" %7.1lf", average);

        if (average >= 90)
            grade = 'A';
        else if (average >= 80)
            grade = 'B';
        else if (average >= 70)
            grade = 'C';
        else if (average >= 60)
            grade = 'D';
        else
            grade = 'F';

        printf (" %5c", grade);

        //Test if the student's name in count 
        //is before the student's name in index_of_first
        for (index = 0; index < students[count].num_scores; index++)
            printf (" %3.0lf", students[count].scores[index]);


        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

If someone could give me the spot where my error is and a possible solution, I would be very much appreciative.

The results that I am getting now are:

```
Welcome to the automated grade book program. Version 2.0
Enter Student data filename:grades.txt
```

It just stops and does nothing here.

Comment: What is the output you are getting now?

Answer (score 0):

Your input file has the wrong format. I mean, first you want to read the number of students, and then in your loop, you want to get ID, name and grades. But your input file has no student number line at first, instead it has "ID, NAME, GRADE" line. Changing your grades.txt file like this will solve the problem:

```
3
2442
Kapowski, Kelly
87 99 100 87 88 -99
1254
Slater, A.C.
90 100 -99
8742
Morris, Zack
77 65 50 80 66 -99
```

Comment: @user3067307 Did changing input text file solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably zero in on the problem in no time if you check the return value from the scanf calls. `scanf` returns the number of successfully converted items, so it should be

```
if (scanf ("%s", ...) == 1) {
    /* OK */
} else {
    /* Problem. */
}
...
if (fscanf (input_file, "%lf", &value) == 1) {
    /* OK */
} else {
    /* Problem. */
}
```